# Facebook GraphAPI App actions on wall post not working

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-wall

I've been trying to post app specific actions to wall posts but nothing seems to help. What am I doing wrong?

```
  oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "http://myurl.com/fb_auth")
  token = oauth.get_access_token(params[:code])
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new token
  p graph.put_wall_post("explodingdog!", {
    :link => "http://youtube.com/", 
    :caption => "Youtube",
    :actions => [{:name => "Share", :link => "http://google.com"}]
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert actions to JSON string, using json gem this is how you will do it:

> gem install json

then use to_json to convert your array to json:

```
 oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "http://myurl.com/fb_auth")
  token = oauth.get_access_token(params[:code])
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new token
  p graph.put_wall_post("explodingdog!", {
    :link => "http://youtube.com/", 
    :caption => "Youtube",
    :actions => [{:name => "Share", :link => "http://google.com"}].to_json
  })
```

You are done :)